# Ubercart 2 / Drupal 6 Multiple Currency Support

Tags: php, drupal, currency, ubercart

Is there someone here successfully implemented a shopping site that supports multicurrency? (Ubercart 2 + Drupal 6)  I've been solving this for weeks already and im having a hard time implementing this?

I've searched a lot, tried, and installed ubercart/drupal community modules, even patched and hacked ubercart's core, but still unsuccessful.  Most modules are not compatible with latest Ubercart and Drupal 6 combination.

Can someone help me with the correct modules to implement this?

thanks

Comment: You might have better luck addressing this on the Drupal & Ubercart community itself

Comment: See if it helps: http://drupal.org/node/449322 am also agreed with Gary's comment.

Comment: Are you after automatic currency conversion, or separate price per product per currency?